# The location of image

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using ecapture library to capture a picture in Python using the following code, where is the image file saved in my PC and if it is not saved how to save it?

```
from ecapture import ecapture as ec
ec.capture(0,"test","img.jpg")
```

I tried this:

```
with open('random.jpg', 'w') as file:
file.write(ec.capture(0, "youLookBeautiful", False))
```

but that what I received if the random.jpg: image not loaded

Comment: It is saved in your current path. Path where you are running this python script. If you want it to be saved elsewhere, please specify an absolute path in `"a/b/img.jpg"`.

Comment: so helpful. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used

```
ec.capture(0,"test","img.jpg")
```

Where

0 = cameraId

"test" = window name

"img.jpg" = save name

So yes you saved it and the location is where your current script is at

If you don't want to save it

```
 ec.capture(0,"test",False)
```